# Can I copy files based on schema?

Tags: xcode

I have a 3rd party library that I'm using and, depending on the build scheme, I want to copy a .plist that the library depends on. They specifically look for their .plist so I can't just put those entries into the info.plist.

Can I do that?

Using Xcode 7

Comment: You can always create a new target to include this .plist file and then associate the scheme with this target. If you don't/can't create new target, there's also a more tricky way to achieve this.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.